# ActiveRecord returns model objects with un-initialized associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a simple join query which in some cases returns ActiveRecord objects with uninitialized associations, and I try to understand why. (My setup: rails 2.3.8 with MySQL)

Here are my models:

```
class Member
has_many :twitter_status_relations
 //has some more unrelated associations
end

class TwitterStatus
  has_many :twitter_status_relations 
end

class TwitterStatusRelation
 belongs_to :member
 belongs_to :twitter_status
end
```

And here is the query I perform:

```
 result = TwitterStatusRelation.all(:joins => :twitter_status, 
:conditions=>{:twitter_statuses=>{:sent_at=>1.month.ago..DateTime.now}}, :include=>:member,:group=>"twitter_status_relations.member_id")
```

Now, when I run in it the first time in the app, it works fine:

```
print result[0].member, result[0].member.class.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many)
#=> <Member...>, [<ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssociationReflection,...]
```

BUT, when I run it again, and try accessing any association of the member, I get nil exception. Print shows the following:

```
print result[0].member, result[0].member.class.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many)
#=> <Member...>, [-- empty ---]
```

Looks like the member object doesn't have any associations, and so when I try to access any of it, I get an exception.

Do you have any idea why ActiveRecord wouldn't initialize associations of the returned objects in some cases? I would appreciate any half-idea because I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SQL the above query produces (Ran posted the question on my behalf). The SQL has more fields then the query, because I simplified the query when posting it, removing conditions that aren't relevant to the problem.

> ```
> SELECT `twitter_status_relations`.`id` AS t0_r0,
> ```
>
> `twitter_status_relations`.`twitter_status_id` AS t0_r1,
>   `twitter_status_relations`.`source_twitter_identity_id` AS t0_r2,
>   `twitter_status_relations`.`relation_type` AS t0_r3,
>   `twitter_status_relations`.`relation_data` AS t0_r4,
>   `twitter_status_relations`.`linked_twitter_identity_id` AS t0_r5,
>   `twitter_status_relations`.`user_id` AS t0_r6,
>   `twitter_status_relations`.`linked_member_id` AS t0_r7, `members`.`id`
>   AS t1_r0, `members`.`user_id` AS t1_r1, `members`.`name` AS t1_r2,
>   `members`.`email` AS t1_r3, `members`.`member_rating` AS t1_r4,
>   `members`.`created_at` AS t1_r5, `members`.`updated_at` AS t1_r6,
>   `members`.`merged_with_member_id` AS t1_r7, `members`.`engage_rating`
>   AS t1_r8, `members`.`support_rating` AS t1_r9,
>   `members`.`user_engage_rating` AS t1_r10,
>   `members`.`user_support_rating` AS t1_r11,
>   `members`.`influence_rating` AS t1_r12, `members`.`twitter_username`
>   AS t1_r13, `members`.`lead_rating` AS t1_r14,
>   `members`.`follow_rating` AS t1_r15, `members`.`unfollow_rating` AS
>   t1_r16, `members`.`followers_count` AS t1_r17, `members`.`hidden` AS
>   t1_r18 FROM `twitter_status_relations` LEFT OUTER JOIN `members` ON
>   `members`.id = `twitter_status_relations`.linked_member_id WHERE
>   (`twitter_status_relations`.`user_id` = 1 AND
>   `twitter_status_relations`.`relation_type` IN(
>   'mention','reply','received_dm','retweet','link','term','hashtag' )
>   AND `twitter_status_relations`.`linked_member_id` IN(
>   83995,128457,21421,138316,128455,97475,128453,436231,82236,441208,138564,138337,436223,436222,441093,21194,441088,441092,438998,442752,138331,138327,138325,444897,9277,12,509521,13,15,534511,7606,7447,200,7,4,17200,5,652302,1,5536,18770,652301,214082,150870,436228,81204,436225,662513,138608,138338
>   )) AND `twitter_status_relations`.id IN (8304, 26493, 113492, 113638,
>   1, 6, 41213, 113493, 20, 26173) GROUP BY
>   twitter_status_relations.linked_member_id ORDER BY
>   members.member_rating